# How to get 10 of the results in every group of a table using Hive sql?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table

[image]

I want to group the data by class, then every class pick out two of the data,whatever sorting or not.

then get results like this.

[image]

How to write the sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by class order by class) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

If you want two particular rows -- such as the two highest scoring or lowest scoring -- then adjust the `order by` clause.

Comment: It works,Thanks.I tried some complicated sql and failed,bui this sql is very useful.